# Why the database didn't update anything although terminal shows "Completed 200" for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller code is like these:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find params[:id]
end

def update
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "success!"
  else      
    flash[:notice] = "fail!"
  end
end

attr_accessor :username, :introduction, :first_name, :last_name

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :introduction, :first_name, :last_name)
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url =>edit_path(@user), :method => :PUT do |f| %>
<%= f.label :username %><br>
<%= f.text_field :username %>
<br>
<%= f.label :Introduction %><br>
<%= f.text_area :introduction %>
<br>
<%= f.label :FirstName %><br>
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
<br>
<%= f.label :LastName %><br>
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>
<br>
<%= f.submit "Save changes"%><% end %>
```

And the terminal is:

```
    Started PUT "/profile/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-06 04:30:05 -0500
    Processing by ProfileController#edit as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eBvvAG892DTOFzYuFTKPCgbOuSQXB8BVOub7A8CgaPHLW2vaBFMpUGNHhgYZednfd5pqICCy1DykIarD7QYtIg==", "user"=>{"username"=>"aaa", "introduction"=>"aaaaa", "first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a"}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"1"}
      User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
      Notification Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"
      Chat Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "chats" WHERE "chats"."sender_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["sender_id", 1]]
      Chat Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "chats" WHERE "chats"."recip_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recip_id", 1]]
      User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
      CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
      Rendered profile/edit.html.erb within layouts/game (1.5ms)
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
    Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 28.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

But database is not updating:

> 1|du.1@osu.edu|$2a$11$2WHUjqQHU1gtlzw3ObXgVeE7dGG1qby2tLmATeoUyMnh1cg5wXv86||||3|2017-12-06 08:43:44.469588|2017-12-06 05:32:19.252680|127.0.0.1|127.0.0.1|2017-12-05 17:04:39.689636|2017-12-06 08:43:44.470487||1970-1-1|||This guy is lazy. Without an Introduction.|

Comment: Post code and logs, not images of code and logs.

Comment: I'm betting on validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is definitely askew. Look here:

```
Started PUT "/profile/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-06 04:30:05 -0500
```

You're doing a `PUT` to `/profile/1/edit`. Conventionally, you would do a `GET` to `/profile/1/edit` which would map to the `edit` action of your `ProfileController`. So, perhaps you have your routes mis-configured because I would normally expect that to throw an error. Instead (if your console output is correct), `PUT "/profile/1/edit"` is mapping to the `edit` action of your `ProfileController`, as you can see here:

```
Processing by ProfileController#edit as HTML
```

And, naturally, `edit` doesn't do any updating:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find params[:id]
end
```

So, no changes to your database.

By the way, are you using Devise or something like that? As you can see, you're loading your `user` twice:

```
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  ...
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
```

So I wonder if, in `edit`,

```
def edit
  @user = User.find params[:id]
end
```

`@user = User.find params[:id]` is even needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use safe `user_params` instead of `params[:user]`:

```
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  # ...
```

BTW you probably don't need `attr_accessor :username, :introduction, :first_name, :last_name` line in your controller.